# Doctrine2 Many-to-one bidirectional relationship not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to do a bidirectional association between 2 entities. The problem is that from Book I can get their Owner, but from Owner I can't get the books owned.

Here is the important part of the code:

**Acme\BookBundle\Entity\Book;**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="owned_books")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $owner;

/**
 * Get owner
 *
 * @return Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getOwner()
{
    return $this->owner;
}
```

**Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User;**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\BookBundle\Entity\Book", mappedBy="owner")
 */
protected $owned_books;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->owned_books = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get owned_books
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getOwnedBooks()
{
    return $this->owned_books;
}
```

Then, to get the data:

**This Works**

```
$book = $this->getDoctrine()
  ->getRepository('BookBundle:Book')
  ->find(1);

$owner = $book->getOwner()->getFirstName();
```

**This Doesn't work** ( Gives Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection::getName() )

```
$owner = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
    ->find(1);

$books = $owner->getOwnedBooks()->getName();
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$owner->getOwnedBooks() is a collection of Owners. Try to loop through the collection with a foreach loop.

```
$books = $owner->getOwnedBooks();
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->getName() . ' <br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear: you're trying to get the name of a collection of book, instead of trying to get the name of a single book.